# Pointer to Pointer to a Structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

I have following structure that contains two integer values.

```
struct data
{
 int v1;
 int v2;
};

/*some functions on struct data*/

struct data* create(int v1,int v2);
void printData(struct data *d);
```

Now I have the following structure vec wich will kind of act like a list and this structure has size and a pointer to a pointer to a structure of type data.

```
struct vec
{
 int size;
 struct data **array;
};

/*possible functions for vec structure*/
struct vec* createVec();
void addFront(struct vec *v, struct data* dta);
```

Since i am a beginner to pointers i would like to clarify and confirm my understanding.

1. **struct data **array;** I am trying to figure out how this is working so i have drawn a visualization of what it might possibly be and would appreciate if someone can confirm if i am correct or not.

[image: pointer to pointer to structure of type data]

I know this is not the greatest data structure etc this is being done strictly to help me clarify my understanding in pointers.

Comment: what was the question again? why not try it yourself and ask after it goes wrong?

Comment: question is if my visualization is correct. i have drawn what i think is going on but i could be wrong. @zubergu is it clear now

Comment: `struct data **array;` is not what your image is shown. It is just a 4 byte memory with a garbage value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your visualization is fine.

If we look at your diagram, we'd expect `vec->array[0]` (the first element of your array) to be a pointer to `struct data`, right?

The array indexing operation (`[0]`) will *de-reference* the first element, which means stripping a pointer from the type.

So, if the type of `array` is `struct data **`, the type of `array[0]` will be `struct data *` (notice one fewer `*`), which is what we expect.

Answer (score 1):

To help you clarify everything in your mind (and your code), you can do the following:

`typedef struct data* data_ptr`

Then, the struct vec can be written as

```
struct vec
{
 int size;
 data_ptr *array;
};
```

So, array is indeed a pointer to a pointer to a data struct. 
Array however is a misleading name, since you could be able to get what you want with other data structures like lists etc.
If you decide to stick with the array, then you should allocate memory correctly and free it at the end, and the structure looks like what you have drawn.

Therefore, (after the correct initializations), `array[i]` will give you a pointer to the i-th data struct, and `array[i]->v1` should give you the v1 value of the i-th struct.